# Making a function call only even indexed parts of a numpy array of 2d arrays

Tags: python, numpy

This my data that i got from numpy:

```py
array = [np.array([868., 905.]), np.array([827., 905.]), np.array([785., 905.]), np.array([743., 905.]), np.array([701., 905.]), np.array([659., 905.]), np.array([617., 905.]), np.array([575., 905.]), np.array([533., 905.]), np.array([491., 905.]), np.array([449., 905.]), np.array([407., 905.]), np.array([365., 905.]), np.array([323., 905.]), np.array([281., 905.]), np.array([239., 905.]), np.array([197., 905.]), np.array([155., 905.])]
```

So I want to be able to call from a function only the odd indexes and the the function will call the even indexes of this array. If there is a better way to achieve this please let me know. Like this:

```
function1[array[odd]]
function2[array[even]]
```

One of my ideas was to split the array into two arrays then call those arrays, but I didn't know how to do that either.

Comment: You just need to get an array with first or the second value, right? Simply convert this list to np.array and run `arr[:,0]` for odd and `arr[:,1]` for even.

Comment: function2 should call the array then check: [868,905], [785,905],[701,905]...

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains typos. Please try to be clearer in your question. Do you want to do the following?

```py
array = [np.array([868., 905.]), np.array([827., 905.]), np.array([785., 905.]), np.array([743., 905.]), np.array([701., 905.]), np.array([659., 905.]), np.array([617., 905.]), np.array([575., 905.]), np.array([533., 905.]), np.array([491., 905.]), np.array([449., 905.]), np.array([407., 905.]), np.array([365., 905.]), np.array([323., 905.]), np.array([281., 905.]), np.array([239., 905.]), np.array([197., 905.]), np.array([155., 905.])]

def get_even(array):
    return [sub_array[0] for sub_array in array]

def get_odd(array):
    return [sub_array[1] for sub_array in array]
```